# Apache HTTPClient5 - How to Prevent Connection/Stream Refused

Tags: apache-httpclient-5.x

## Problem Statement

### Context

- I'm a Software Engineer in Test running order permutations of Restaurant Menu Items to confirm that they succeed order placement w/ the POS

  - In short, this POSTs a JSON payload to an endpoint which then validates the order w/ a POS to define success/fail/other
  - Where POS, and therefore Transactions per Second (TPS), may vary, but each Back End uses the same core handling
  - This can be as high as ~22,000 permutations per item, in easily manageable JSON size, that need to be handled as quickly as possible
  - The Network can vary wildly depending upon the Restaurant, and/or Region, one is testing

    - E.g. where some have a much higher latency than others
  - Therefore, the HTTPClient should be able to intelligently negotiate the same content & endpoint regardless of this

### Direct Problem

- I'm using Apache's HTTP Client 5 w/ PoolingAsyncClientConnectionManager to execute both the GET for the Menu contents, and the POST to check if the order succeeds
- This works out of the box, but sometimes loses connections w/ `Stream Refused`, specifically:

  - `org.apache.hc.core5.http2.H2StreamResetException: Stream refused`
- No individual tuning seems to work across all network contexts w/ variable latency, that I can find
- Following the stacktrace seems to indicate it is that the stream had closed already, therefore needs a way to keep it open or not execute an already-closed connection

```
if (connState == ConnectionHandshake.GRACEFUL_SHUTDOWN) {
    throw new H2StreamResetException(H2Error.PROTOCOL_ERROR, "Stream refused");
}
```

### Some Attempts to Fix Problem

- Tried to use Search Engines to find answers but there are few hits for HTTPClient5
- Tried to use [official documentation](https://tillster.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/OpEO/pages/1678213346) but this is sparse
- Changing max connections per route to a reduced number, shifting inactivity validations, or connection time to live

  - Where the inactivity checks may fix the POST, but stall the GET for some transactions
  - And that tuning for one region/restaurant may work for 1 then break for another, w/ only the Network as variable

```java
PoolingAsyncClientConnectionManagerBuilder builder = PoolingAsyncClientConnectionManagerBuilder
        .create()
        .setTlsStrategy(getTlsStrategy())
        .setMaxConnPerRoute(12)
        .setMaxConnTotal(12)
        .setValidateAfterInactivity(TimeValue.ofMilliseconds(1000))
        .setConnectionTimeToLive(TimeValue.ofMinutes(2))
        .build();
```

- Shifting to a custom RequestConfig w/ different timeouts

```java
private HttpClientContext getHttpClientContext() {
    RequestConfig requestConfig = RequestConfig.custom()
            .setConnectTimeout(Timeout.of(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
            .setResponseTimeout(Timeout.of(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
            .build();

    HttpClientContext httpContext = HttpClientContext.create();
    httpContext.setRequestConfig(requestConfig);
    return httpContext;
}
```

### Initial Code Segments for Analysis

(In addition to the above segments w/ change attempts)

- Wrapper handling to init and get response

```java
public SimpleHttpResponse getFullResponse(String url, PoolingAsyncClientConnectionManager manager, SimpleHttpRequest req) {
            try (CloseableHttpAsyncClient httpclient = getHTTPClientInstance(manager)) {
                httpclient.start();

                CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
                long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                Future<SimpleHttpResponse> future = getHTTPResponse(url, httpclient, latch, startTime, req);

                latch.await();
                return future.get();
            } catch (IOException | InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return new SimpleHttpResponse(999, CommonUtils.getExceptionAsMap(e).toString());
            }
        }
```

- With actual handler and probing code

```java
private Future<SimpleHttpResponse> getHTTPResponse(String url, CloseableHttpAsyncClient httpclient, CountDownLatch latch, long startTime, SimpleHttpRequest req) {
            return httpclient.execute(req, getHttpContext(), new FutureCallback<SimpleHttpResponse>() {

                @Override
                public void completed(SimpleHttpResponse response) {
                    latch.countDown();
                    logger.info("[{}][{}ms] - {}", response.getCode(), getTotalTime(startTime), url);
                }

                @Override
                public void failed(Exception e) {
                    latch.countDown();
                    logger.error("[{}ms] - {} - {}", getTotalTime(startTime), url, e);
                }

                @Override
                public void cancelled() {
                    latch.countDown();
                    logger.error("[{}ms] - request cancelled for {}", getTotalTime(startTime), url);
                }

            });
        }
```

### Direct Question

- Is there a way to configure the client such that it can handle for these variances on its own without explicitly modifying the configuration for each endpoint context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Fixed w/ Combination of the below to Assure Connection Live/Ready

(Or at least is stable)

#### Forcing HTTP 1

```java
HttpAsyncClients.custom()
    .setConnectionManager(manager)
    .setRetryStrategy(getRetryStrategy())
    .setVersionPolicy(HttpVersionPolicy.FORCE_HTTP_1)
    .setConnectionManagerShared(true);
```

#### Setting Effective Headers for POST

- Specifically the close header

  - `req.setHeader("Connection", "close, TE");`
  - Note: Inactivity check helps, but still sometimes gets refusals w/o this

#### Setting Inactivity Checks by Type

- Set POSTs to validate immediately after inactivity

  - Note: Using 1000 for both caused a high drop rate for some systems

```java
PoolingAsyncClientConnectionManagerBuilder
    .create()
    .setValidateAfterInactivity(TimeValue.ofMilliseconds(0))
```

- Set GET to validate after 1s

```java
PoolingAsyncClientConnectionManagerBuilder
    .create()
    .setValidateAfterInactivity(TimeValue.ofMilliseconds(1000))
```

### Given the Error Context

- Tracing the connection problem in stacktrace to AbstractH2StreamMultiplexer
- Shows ConnectionHandshake.GRACEFUL_SHUTDOWN as triggering the stream refusal

```
 if (connState == ConnectionHandshake.GRACEFUL_SHUTDOWN) {
    throw new H2StreamResetException(H2Error.PROTOCOL_ERROR, "Stream refused");
}
```

- Which corresponds to

```java
connState = streamMap.isEmpty() ? ConnectionHandshake.SHUTDOWN : ConnectionHandshake.GRACEFUL_SHUTDOWN;
```

### Reasoning

- If I'm understanding correctly:

  - The connections were being un/intentionally closed

    - However, they were not being confirmed ready before executing again
    - Which caused it to fail because the stream was not viable
  - Therefore the fix works because (it seems)

    - Given Forcing HTTP1 allows for a single context to manage

      - Where HttpVersionPolicy NEGOTIATE/FORCE_HTTP_2 had greater or equivalent failures across the spectrum of regions/menus
    - And it assures that all connections are valid before use
    - And POSTs are always closed due to the close header, which is unavailable to HTTP2
    - Therefore

      - GET is checked for validity w/ reasonable periodicity
      - POST is checked every time, and since it is forcibly closed, it is re-acquired before execution
      - Which leaves no room for unexpected closures

        - And otherwise the potential that it was incorrectly switching to HTTP2

---

Will accept this until a better answer comes along, as this is stable but sub-optimal.